# Create a plane equation from a point and a line (not normal)

Tags: geometry, homework

I have to decide the plane equation in normal form, that goes through the point (3.08,1,4.76) and the line (4.08,3.08,5.76)+ t( 3,6,-3).

I have no idea how to do it. I google it and found some information with three points, or one point and the normal.

I tried this:

```
d = Point[{3.08, 1, 4.76}]
Line[{4.08, 3.08, 5.76} + t  {3, 6, -3}]
d := 3.08, 1, 4.76};
e := {4.08, 3.08, 5.76};
u := e - d;
v := {3, 6, -3};
n := u\[Cross]v;
```

(the last part, I copied from someone else, but it did not work)

I am so frustrated, I hate every second of my math class right now. Please help!

EDIT: My equation has to be in the form:

> x+By+Cz+D=0

.. so I also need to divide everything by A (preferably automatically :)

Comment: I think the key is to find the plane's normal vector.

Comment: After your code (except for the missing parenthesis in the 3rd line) just evaluate ⁣ ⁣ ⁣ ⁣ ⁣ ⁣ ⁣ ⁣ ⁣ ⁣ ⁣ ⁣ ⁣ ⁣ ⁣ ⁣ ⁣ ⁣ ⁣ ⁣ ⁣ ⁣ ⁣ ⁣ ⁣ ⁣ ⁣ ⁣ ⁣ ⁣ ⁣ ⁣ ⁣ ⁣ ⁣ ⁣⁣ ⁣ ⁣ ⁣ ⁣ ⁣ ⁣ ⁣ ⁣ ⁣ ⁣ ⁣ ⁣`({x, y, z} - d).n/n[[1]] == 0 // ExpandAll`

Comment: aside to the question, none of those assignments should be delayed. Use plain `=` when the entire right hand side is known and not subject to later change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the great (!?) thing about recent advances in *Mathematica* is that you can solve such problems without having hardly to worry about the mathematics at all. Just [`Join`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Join.html) the given point to two points on the given line, and use [`RegionMember`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionMember.html) on the [`InfinitePlane`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InfinitePlane.html) containing the three points generated:

```
RegionMember[
  InfinitePlane[{{3.08, 1, 4.76}} ~Join~
    Table[{4.08, 3.08, 5.76} + t {3, 6, -3}, {t, 2}]]][{x, y, z}]
(*
  (x | y | z) ∈ Reals && 
   0.897782 (-3.08 + x) - 0.440089 (-1 + y) + 0.0176036 (-4.76 + z) == 0
*)
```

Comment: Thanks for your message! I don't think THAT great either, since I have no clue about what's going on. Why do you have {t, 2} between curly brackets for example? What did you do in the end with (x | y | z) ∈ Reals && ? And since my equation does not has any A, how do I divide automatically the whole equation with A? That would be a great thing to know!

Comment: @Dovendyr [`DivideSides[eqn, A`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DivideSides.html).

Answer (score 2):

```
P = {x0, y0, z0};
A = {x1, y1, z1};
V = {v1, v2, v3};
n = Cross[P - A, V]
```

---

**Update 1**

The value returned (`n`) is a normal vector of the intended plane. Given the normal vector $ \hat{n}=(n_1, n_2, n_3) $, the equation of the plane should be

$
n_1(x-x_0)+n_2(y-y_0)+n_3(z-z_0)=0
$

---

**Update 2**

Well, the plane equation (of $ (x, y, z) $) is

```
S = {x, y, z};
eq = Dot[n, S - P] == 0
```

---

**Update 3**

The above `eq` is in the form of $ a x + b y + c z + d = 0 $. And the constant term (interception?) $ d $ can be obtained via

```
d = First[CoefficientArrays[eq, {x, y, z}]]
```

In this case it is

```
-v3 x1 y0 + v3 x0 y1 + v2 x1 z0 - v1 y1 z0 - v2 x0 z1 + v1 y0 z1
```

and happens to be the determinant of the matrix consisting of `P`,`A`, and `V`:

```
Det[{P, A, V}]
```

Comment: Thank you: I tried 

P = {3.08, 1, 4.76};
A = {4.08, 3.08, 5.76};
V = {3, 6, -3};
Cross[P - A, V] // Simplify

It gives me

: {12.24, -6., 0.24}


Is it the equation I am after? Where is the ''D'' value in that case?

Comment: So you mean I need to calculate the D value by hand with help of the usual formula?

Comment: Hello,

Sorry I missed your update. (how do you make spaces in your comments btw?)

I tried what you wrote and got the reply:
12.24` (-3.08` + x) - 6.` (-1 + y) + 
  0.24000000000000055` (-4.76` + z) == 0

In my exercise, they want the plane equation in the form of x+By+Cz+D=0


So I tried to call the former plane equation P1, and devided it by 12.24. But I get: 


P1 = [12.24` (-3.08` + x) - 6.` (-1 + y) + 
    0.24000000000000055` (-4.76` + z) == 0]
P1/12.24
0.0816993 P1

Comment: Hello again, can I please have some clarification, I still cannot solve it...

Comment: Hi! I'm sorry, I don't understand what v1, v2 and v3 are for, and how the normal is linked to the determinant.

Comment: @Dovendyr `P` is the single point your intended plane would pass; `A` is the initial point of the line and `V` is its directional vector.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to everyone.
The last line that @Coolwater named worked fine after I fixed the missing parenthesis, so I will go for it (until test on Monday, then I will explore how it works!)

I don't understand what happens in the last line though!

```
({x, y, z} - d).n/n[[1]] == 0 // ExpandAll
```

I looked for expand all, so this part I get, but not what happens before and why we need to do that?

Edit: I also wish of course to understand why

```
InfinitePlane[{{3.08, 1, 4.76}}~Join~
     Table[{4.08, 3.08, 5.76} + t {3, 6, -3}, {t, 2}]]][{x, y, z}];
```

there is {t, 2} in that part, and why comes x,y,z in a box at the end.