# Normal of plane given three points

Tags: linear-algebra

Is there a command (or a combination of commands) that takes three points of a plane and outputs the normal vector of that plane?
I'm told there is a ready way of automating this, but have been unable to find it.

Comment: `Hyperplane` maybe work.

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Please include Mathematica code that you have tried out so far. Code can be copied from the cell in your notebook and pasted in the Edit window; use the `{  }` button in the edit window for formatting code. If you are starting out with Mathematica, then the introductory [book](https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/) written by the inventor is a great online resource.

Comment: Similar to [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/245503/graphing-a-normal-vector-to-a-plane-from-the-origin), [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/252684/plotting-normal-vectors-to-planes-and-to-paraboloids-picture-seems-inaccurate) and perhaps [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/172867/create-a-plane-equation-from-a-point-and-a-line-not-normal/172870#172870).

Answer (score 4):

In 3D, "Cross" can be used to get a vector perpendicular to 2 given vectors.

Call the given vectors p1,p2,p3, then Cross[p2-p1,p3-p1] is a vector perpendicular to the plane through p1,p2,p3.

Here is an example:

```
SeedRandom[3];
{p1, p2, p3} = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {3, 3}];
p4 = Cross[p2 - p1, p3 - p1];
Graphics3D[{
  Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, #}] & /@ {p1, p2, p3}, Red, Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, p4}],
  Green, Opacity[0.5], InfinitePlane[{p1, p2, p3}]
  }]
```

[image]

Comment: I will usually recommend Daniel's method, but the method hinted in Roman's comment can be made to work: `Normal[Last[CoefficientArrays[Det[PadRight[Prepend[{p1, p2, p3}, {x, y, z}], {4, 4}, 1]], {x, y, z}]]]`